# Resolve Absolute / Alias Imports in Components with Storybook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, gatsby, storybook

I'm using `gatsby-plugin-alias-imports` to be able to do absolute imports like so: `import { colors } from "@styles/theme";` This is set up in the `gatsby-config`. Now I've just added storybook to my project. Since storybook doesn't run through gatsby, the alias imports won't resolve and I get an error:

> ERROR in ./src/components/Button/index.js Module not found: Error:
>   Can't resolve '@styles/theme' in  ...

This makes sense. Storybook doesn't know what to do with `@styles...` - but  how can I fix this?

Answer (score 23):

You need to configure Storybook's Webpack to follow the same directive by adding `./src` to the resolutions array. In your `.storybook/webpack.config.js` file, add this to the body of the function being exported (assuming you're destructuring `config` from the first argument):

```js
config.resolve.modules = [
  path.resolve(__dirname, "..", "src"),
  "node_modules",
]
```

Your `webpack.config.js` file should look something like this when you're done:

```js
const path = require("path")

module.exports = ({ config }) => {
  // a bunch of other rules here

  config.resolve.modules = [
    path.resolve(__dirname, "..", "src"),
    "node_modules",
  ]

  // Alternately, for an alias:
  config.resolve.alias = {
    "@styles": path.resolve(__dirname, "..", "src", "styles")
  }

  return config
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I don't see how this would let webpack know where `@styles` points to? Also, `@styles` might not point to `src/styles` but to a completely different path? Or am I misunderstanding your answer here?

Comment: @R.Kohlisch You just need to update `src` with the path to `@styles`. Alternately you can just define an alias the same way. [Documentation for that is here.](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolvealias)

Answer (score 8):

You need to tell the webpack config for storybook to resolve the path aliases you have set in your `tsconfig.json` file.

Inside your `.storybook/main.js` file, you need to add the following.

```js
const TsconfigPathsPlugin = require('tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin')

module.exports = {
    "webpackFinal": async config => {
        config.resolve.plugins.push(new TsconfigPathsPlugin())
        return config
    }
}
```

This adds the `tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin` package to the storybook webpack config's resolve plugins and uses your `tsconfig.json` to resolve the path aliases.

This is also the exact way it would be done inside any webpack config file. I have dealt a lot with making path aliases work and this is the absolute easiest way to do it and will work every time.

Comment: Super simple and worked for me! Thanks!!!

Comment: This only works for Webpack4 and below, tsconfigPathsPlugin is not currently compatible with 5+

Answer (score 2):

In case you use `@storybook/vite-builder`. This neat config works for me

```
const tsconfigPaths = require("vite-tsconfig-paths");
...
module.exports = {
    ...
    framework: "@storybook/react",
    core: {
        "builder": "@storybook/builder-vite"
    },
    async viteFinal(config) {
        config.plugins.push(tsconfigPaths.default());

        return config;
    },
};
```

Comment: Worked perfectly for me.  Don't forget `yarn -D vite-tsconfig-paths`

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you need to create custom babel config for storybook. Include there your configurations of `gatsby-plugin-alias-imports`

https://storybook.js.org/docs/configurations/custom-babel-config/

Answer (score 0):

**There is a great possibility that you will find your solution here.**

Resolve alias in webpack config: https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/3339