# Storybook - no stories showing up in typescript project with custom webpack / babel

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, storybook

I am trying to set up Storybook in a project.  My project is runing on react@^16, and I'm using typescript, with a custom babel and webpack setup for development and build.  To set up storybook, I did

```js
npx sb init
```

This installs everything needed. It puts a `.storybook` folder in the root folder, and a `stories` folder in my `src` folder with some prefab components and stories in `tsx` format (which is what I want):

[image]

[image]

The `.storybook/main.js` file seems fine:

```js
module.exports = {
  "stories": [
    "../src/**/*.stories.mdx",
    "../src/**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|ts|tsx)"
  ],
  "addons": [
    "@storybook/addon-links",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials"
  ]
}
```

And the average .stories.js file automatically installed by `npx sb init` also seems fine:

```js
import React from 'react';
// also exported from '@storybook/react' if you can deal with breaking changes in 6.1
import { Story, Meta } from '@storybook/react/types-6-0';

import { Header, HeaderProps } from './Header';

export default {
  title: 'Example/Header',
  component: Header,
} as Meta;

const Template: Story<HeaderProps> = (args) => <Header {...args} />;

export const LoggedIn = Template.bind({});
LoggedIn.args = {
  user: {},
};

export const LoggedOut = Template.bind({});
LoggedOut.args = {};
```

But when I run `npm run storybook`, the storybook landing page has no stories.  Even though it had installed some default stories to start playing with.  It says:

```
Oh no! Your Storybook is empty. Possible reasons why:
The glob specified in main.js isn't correct.
No stories are defined in your story files.
```

As requested, [here](https://github.com/slutske22/20-maps) is a link to the repo so you can dig a bit deeper into the structure, weback config, etc.  Note I have *not* committed the `npx sb init` changes yet, so you won't see the files there, only my starting point just before running the `sb init`.

I haven't had any issues getting `npx sb init` to work with a standard create-react-app, but with my custom webpack build and typescript, its just empty.  What's going wrong?

#### Edit: Additional detail

I realize that just running `npx sb init`, then `npm run storybook` throws this error:

```js
ERROR in ./.storybook/preview.js-generated-config-entry.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'core-js/modules/es.array.filter'
```

Based on [this thread](https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/11255), installing `core-js@3` solves the problem and storybook runs, though with no stories.

Comment: Are your stories files actually exporting stories? Only asking because I've done this in the past by mistake!

Comment: They `.stories.js` files seem fine...I added one to the question for clarification.  These are the default files brought in by `npx sb init`, not even any story files I wrote myself yet.  I literally just did an `npx sb init` and then `npm run storybook` one after another, and the default setup is showing an empty storybook.

Comment: I think `npx sb init` needs a CRA project to work, try debugging the webpack config with `npm run storybook --debug-webpack` to get more details about what is being run and compare it with the one used in CRA

Comment: Could you please share a GitHub link for this repo, so that this can be debugged in a better way?

Comment: I added the link.  Note the repo does not have the files added from `sb init`, as I'm not going to commit them until it starts working.  Just imagine cloning the repo and running `npx sb init`, and you'll be exactly where I'm at in the problem.

Comment: @diedu adding the `--debug-webpack` flag doesn't seem to do anything, no difference in output in the console.  There must be a way to bridge the gap between using `npx sb init` for CRA and a custom webpacl/babel build.  What could be missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems like the babel plugin `transform-es2015-modules-amd` doesn't fit right with `storybook` since `sb` still uses your babel configuration.

You might need to remove it then it would work:

```js
{
  "plugins": [
     // "transform-es2015-modules-amd", // Remove this plugin
   ]
}
```

If you want to have a special babel configuration for storybook, place it `.storybook/.babelrc` so the configuration would be simple like this:

`.storybook/.babelrc`:

```js
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react", "@babel/preset-typescript"]
}
```

NOTE: You might miss to forget install `@babel/preset-typescript` to help you transform your typescript code.

Comment: This was it.  I tried it both ways, both ways work.  I'm not sure why I needed the `transform-es2015-modules-amd`, as my project still builds without it.  Thank you!  How did you pinpoint this?

Comment: Welp, now I have a new issue.  Since you're knowledgable about this, maybe you can help. When trying to create a story from my components, I get the error: `Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'esri/Basemap' in '/.../GitHub/20-maps/src/components/chapters/protests_us'`.  Why is storybook not knowing to look for  node modules in the `node_modules` folder?  I did some searching and some people recommended [adding a `resolve`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60634295/resolve-absolute-alias-imports-in-components-with-storybook) to the webpack config, but I already have that in my config.

Comment: I'm not sure if I get you right since `node_modules` is supposed to be resolved correctly. Plus, your `webpack` configuration is unrelated to the storybook's one (it has its own configuration but you can customize it though). Can you push your change to the repo so I can check for you?

Comment: the changes are pushed, with all the storybook files and everything.  thank you so much for looking at this

Comment: I did check your repo again. Unfortunately I couldn't see where is your `esri` package listed in `package.json`. Did you miss install it?

Comment: So all the `esri/X` modules come from the `arcgis-js-api`, which is automatically installed when you install `@arcgis/webpack-plugin`, which is in my package.json.  The webpack config of the project uses the arcgis webpack plugin, which tells the project to looks for all `esri/` modules in the `arcgis-js-api` folder.  Should I add this to the storybook webpack config somehow?  It seems like storybook is trying to look for node modules in the same folder as the file thats importing them though...

Comment: I dropped you another hint to deal with `arcgis-js-api` as a new answer since it has a few steps to follow up

Comment: This one worked for me in angular as well.
Just leave out the @babel/preset-react and you're good to go

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have problems with the stories path, try to save only "../src/**/*.stories.js" in your config to see if its the reason

```
  "stories": [
    "../src/**/*.stories.mdx",
    "../src/**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|ts|tsx)"
  ]
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're suggesting here.  The `stories` property in your answer is identical to the `stories` in my question.  Are you suggesting removing the `addons`?  I tried that and it gives me errors about not knowing how to process .svgs.

Comment: I ment you can try to change the stories path for example check if it can get stories from the more simple  path like "stories": ["../src/**/*.stories.js" ]

Comment: This worked for me. On Ubuntu the `*.@(js|md)` syntax was working fine, but on Windows it does not. I changed it to `*.js` and now it finds the stories on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

In case of dealing with `arcgis-js-api` in `sb`, you have to declare `@arcgis/webpack-plugin` in storybook's webpack configuration by adding to its config.

Here are a few steps you have to do:

- Add `webpackFinal` property in `.storybook/main.js` with following content:

```js
const ArcGISPlugin = require('@arcgis/webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    // ...
    webpackFinal: (config) => {
        // Add your plugin
        config.plugins.push(
            new ArcGISPlugin(),
        );
        
        // Since this package has used some node's API so you might have to stop using it as client side
        config.node = {
            ...config.node,
            process: false,
            fs: "empty"
        };

        return config;
    }
};
```

- One more thing to be aware of, some components are importing `scss` files, so you might need to support it by adding a scss addon `'@storybook/preset-scss'`

```
// Install
npm i -D  @storybook/preset-scss css-loader sass-loader style-loader


// Add to your current addons
{
  addons: ['@storybook/addon-links', '@storybook/addon-essentials', '@storybook/preset-scss'],
}
```

Comment: Dude you are amazing.  This worked.  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Like a tmhao2005 say. Storybook still uses your babel configuration. And this is the intended behavior. [This thread at github](https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/12967) also describes how the fix similar issue.

Updated your config `.storybook/main.js`.

If you use `.babelrc`:

```
babel: async options => ({ ...options, babelrc: false })
```

Or `.babel.config.js`:

```
babel: async options => ({ ...options, configFile: false })
```

Comment: What if I don't use either of those?